# SQL Import With Identity Trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, compare

I have a database that I created using SQL Export tool, but now see that I didn't write out the primary keys and constraints. Unfortunately, it's the only copy I have with data.

I've created a blank database structure with the proper keys in place and am now trying to import the data into the new database using the Import data wizard in SQL 2012. In the mappings settings, I've selected enable identity insert. But, I keep running into error after error.

I then tried to use the SQL Compare tool in Visual Studio 2012, thinking I could generate ALTER table scripts to create the Primary Keys and constraints on the database holding the data, but I can only seem to get it to generate CREATE TABLE scripts. Obviously, doing this will drop the table and thus my data.

Ultimately, I just want a database with keys and constraints and data all together. I've exhausted my knowledge and am not quite sure how to proceed at this point.

I'm hoping some of you guru's have some tricks up your sleeve that will help me out. Any help is sincerely appreciated in advance.

Comment: What errors are you encountering?

Comment: Unless the errors are Key Violations, you'd probably be better off applying the structure changes to the data, rather than trying to inject the data into the structures.

Comment: If there are GAPS where the data will go into the target datanase and the tables have values lower than the GAPS you could try SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF TABLE A - INSERT RECORDS TO A THEN TURN ON IDENTITY_INSERT. This is only an option for one table at a given time in your connection work. Basically, allowing you to specify the values for the IDENTITY columns in the gaps.

Comment: I thought I was turning off identity insert by checking "Enable Identity Insert", but I think it kept getting held up with the constraints to foreign key tables. I ended up doing what RBarryYoung suggested and updated the structure. Tedious, but done now. I appreciate the help and comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "Enable insert identity" works for me.

Perhaps  the next time you import a table with identity fields you can try import the identity field, how to do so?:

for each table you import in the "Select source tables and views" step of the wizard

select table>edit mappings > edit sql >

The code will be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[miTable] (
[idField] [int] NOT NULL,
[anotherColumns] varchar ...
)
```

modify it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[miTable] (
[idField] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[anotherColumns] varchar ...
)
```

don't forget to  enable insert identity as well.